# Parse: Authorization required from Postman client

Tags: parse-platform, postman

This question is a little out of the norm and I hope it is suited for SO, however if it is not appropriate let me know an appropriate board and I will move it there.

I'm writing an evaluation report for an API assignment at University, and I am required to use the `Postman` web client to make requests to the API I am evaluating.

Currently when I send a request, Parse requires me to provide a username and password (I'd expect this), however when I enter my email and password I always get an `Unauthorized User` JSON object returned.

I have tried going to my dashboard in Parse and setting a new password there, however I am still unable to log in via Postman - has anybody experienced a similar problem before?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Currently, what are you settings for Postman. What are your suppose to be sending? Is it suppose to be a POST or GET request?

Comment: Trying to send a GET request using : `https://api.parse.com/1/classes/TestObject`

Comment: @MaxBaldwin I haven't set any auth stuff - where would I put my application ID and Key in Postman?

Comment: If it is a get request, postman has a section for URL parameters. Apologies, I'm not at my computer right now

Comment: Thanks Max, ill look into that, feel free to post an answer later if you get time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a GET request with Postman, you can pass URL parameters along with your request by clicking the following "URL params" button on the right side of the screen:

[image]

That should give you the following menu:
[image]

Make sure you enter your "URL Parameter Key" exactly how your documentation specifies.

Comment: Have it working but essentially I followed these steps in the end - thanks for your time:)